# What Cell,Table can I use to create a grid of only images in every cell, in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt, web-applications, grid, cell

I need to create a GWT application that handle the buying of films. So I have to show in a grid (not in a list, I don't like the view) these cell containing image and info about the film like this:( http://static.ipaditalia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/mzl.sckskoqz.480x480-75.jpg ). I think that I need of a grid showing I think, to obtain something like but I wouldn't know to start. thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple FlowPanel as a container, and add each image with a float set to "left".

Alternatively, you can use a flex-box model with `flex-flow: row wrap` on a container.

You don't need any widgets for this. This is simple CSS, and it will give you the best performance and the smallest code size.

Comment: also if I want add info, button down every image to permit the purchase? Thanks!

Comment: In terms of layout it does not matter if this is an image or a widget.

Comment: I've put a series of compositeWidget (that contains an htmlPanel table) into a FlowPanel that is into a ScrollPanel. I'm trying to apply the style float: left or flex-flow: row wrap. but it doesn't work. On which part should I use these styles? Thanks a lot

Comment: I Have solved with an HorizontalPanel by now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The draw-back of table-based widgets (like HorizontalPanel) is that they are not responsive, i.e. cannot easily adjust to different screen sizes.